# Using FAM to monitor files moved to NFS mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitor, nfs, network-drive

Since Inotify does not work to monitor NFS mounts I was going to use FAM. In the process of setting it up I found the line below from the docs.

"FAMMoved FAMMoved events never occur.  The name remains defined so that programs that reference it will still compile."

I need to run a command when a file is moved into a monitored directory on a NFS mount. Is there no other way to do this?

Right now there is simply a cron that checks every minute. Trying to improve on that.

Comment: A FAMCreated event will trigger.

Comment: If it is created elsewhere and then moved into the directory it will trigger FAMCreated?

Comment: It should. Because basically this is what happens when a file is moved,iirc : A file of the name is created at the target destination, the old file is copied as a bytestream and afterwards,maybe original file is unlinked. So from the destination's point of view, it really is no difference wether a file is moved or newly created.